# Phonegap 3.6.3; how to execute code while app loads

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile

Phonegap 3.6.3: What is the event which triggers at start of app and help me to decide which page should be displayed at first, everytime app opens?

I wanna check localStorage , only one time as app loads either it have value or null. If it has value display page A otherwise page B. Thanks.

Comment: you need to check the **deviceready** event as shown in the link [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function onBodyLoad()   {       
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);     }       document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    },true);

function onDeviceReady()    {

  // your logic here    
 }
</script>
 </head>

<body onload="onDeviceReady()"></body>
```